# How to implement the Microsoft excel scroll drag feature to the javafx table-view?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm fairly new to coding. I created a demo table view by filling in values via hard coding. I wish to apply the ms excel scroll drag feature to my table view.
I haven't been able to get a solution for the same. 
code snippet would be much helpful.

**My demo Table**

[image: this is the demo table view that i created]

I tried to implement the following code:

```
         private void setupScrolling() {
            scrolltimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            scrolltimeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), "Scoll", (ActionEvent) -> { dragScroll();}));
            table.setOnDragExited(event -> {
                if (event.getX() > 0) {
                    scrollDirection = 1.0 / table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); 
                }
                else {
                    scrollDirection = -1.0 / table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                }
                scrolltimeline.play();
            });
            table.setOnDragEntered(event -> {
                scrolltimeline.stop();
            });
            table.setOnDragDone(event -> {
                scrolltimeline.stop();
            });

        }

      private void dragScroll() {
            ScrollBar sb = getHorizontalScrollBar();
            if (sb != null) {
                double newValue = sb.getValue() + scrollDirection;
                newValue = Math.min(newValue, 1.0);
                newValue = Math.max(newValue, 0.0);
                sb.setValue(newValue);
            }
        }

        private ScrollBar getHorizontalScrollBar() {
            ScrollBar result = null;
            for (Node n : table.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
                if (n instanceof ScrollBar) {
                    ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;
                    if (bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.HORIZONTAL)) {
                        result = bar;
                    }
                }
            }        
            return result;
        }

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(table);
    scrollPane.setContent(vbox);
    scrollPane.setPannable(true);
    Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);
```

Comment: I think having `excel` tag just because the feature is similar is not justified.

Comment: Did you see it `ControlsFX` [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) meets your standards?

Comment: i have tried using the scrollpane .setPannable() method. it works fine for the gridpane , i tried using it on the vbox solely since my tableview is inside the vbox, it works with the vbox too. But doesn't work when i add the tableview into the vbox.